# Hibernate many to many Object values are void

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping, many-to-many

I'm trying to get a many to many mapped `Object` from a `ValueObject`. 
See the structure below:

Owner

Owner_link

Dog

---

See the mapping:

Owner.hbm.xml

```
<set name="dogs"  table="schema.owner_link"  inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" >
    <key foreign-key="none">
        <column name="fk_dog_id" not-null="true"/>
    </key>
    <many-to-many entity-name="de.neo7even.database.pojo.DOG">
        <column name="id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-many>
</set>
```

Dog.hbm.xml

```
<set name="owners" table="schema.owner_link" inverse="true" lazy="true"  fetch="select">
    <key foreign-key="none">
        <column name="fk_dog_id" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <many-to-many entity-name="de.neo7even.database.pojo.Owner">
        <column name="fk_owner_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-many>
</set>
```

The code assigns `null` to my `Dog` variable.

Why fails the code? I'll provide more information if required.

Comment: You have inverse = true on both the hbm files. Please check this http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example/

Comment: I did this one but it didnt helped me. Thank you for your answer